# Attempt to store wrong type in array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, io

I'm receiving this error which I have caught - Attempt to store wrong type in array of objects. The files compile and I need to store the file being read in into the Animals[] array.

Here is the whole file:

```
import java.util.*;                                                                                              
import java.io.BufferedReader;                                                                                   
import java.io.FileReader;                                                                                       
import java.io.IOException;                                                                                      
import java.io.InputStreamReader;                                                                                
import java.io.FileInputStream;                                                                                  
public class Zoo                                                                                                 
{                                                                                                                                                                                                     
private Animals[] animals;                                                                                   
int count;                                                                                                   
public final int Maximum_Count = 20;                                                                         
public boolean constructed = false;                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                            //Default Constructor                                                          
public Zoo()                                                                                                 
{                                                                                                            
    count = 0;                                                                                               
    animals = new Animals[Maximum_Count];                                                                    
}                                                                                                            
                                                                                //Alternate Constructor                   
public Zoo(int inCount, Animals[] inAnimals)                                                                 
{                                                                                                            
    if(validateCount(inCount))                                                                               
    {                                                                                                        
        animals = new Animals[Maximum_Count];                   //Probably Wont have to validate Count       
        for(int ii = 0; ii < Maximum_Count; ii++)                                                            
        {                                                                                                    
            inAnimals[ii] = new Animals(inAnimals[ii]);                                                      
        }                                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                        
}                                                                                                            
                                                                            //Copy Constructor                                                                                                            
public Zoo(Zoo inZoo)                                                                                        
{                                                                                                            
    count = inZoo.getCount();                                                                                
    animals = inZoo.getAnimals();                                                                            
}                                                                                                            

//Mutators                                                                                                   


public void setCount(int inCount)                                                                            
{                                                                                                            
    if(validateCount(inCount))                                                                               
    {                                                                                                        
        count = inCount;                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                        
    else                                                                                                     
    {                                                                                                        
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Count");                                                 
    }                                                                                                        
}                                                                                                            

public void setAnimals(Animals[] inAnimals)                                                                  
{                                                                                                            
    if(inAnimals == null)                                                                                    
    {                                                                                                        
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Animals can not be found, array is empty.");                     
    }                                                                                                        
    else                                                                                                     
    {                                                                                                        
        animals = new Animals[inAnimals.length];                                                             
        for(int ii = 0; ii < inAnimals.length; ii++)                                                         
            {                                                                                                
                animals[ii] = new Animals(inAnimals[ii]);                                                    
            }                                                                                                
    }                                                                                                        
}                                                                                                            

public int getCount()                                                                                        
{                                                                                                            
    return count;                                                                                            
}                                                                                                            

public Animals[] getAnimals()                                                                                
{                                                                                                            
    Animals[] animalsCopy;                                                                                   
    animalsCopy = new Animals[animals.length];                                                               
    for(int ii = 0; ii < animals.length; ii++)                                                               
    {                                                                                                        
         animalsCopy[ii] = new Animals(animals[ii]);                                                         
    }                                                                                                        
    return animalsCopy;                                                                                      
}                                                                                                            


public boolean equals(Object inObject)                                                                       
{                                                                                                            
    Zoo inZoo;                                                                                               
    boolean same = false;                                                                                    
    if(inObject instanceof Zoo)                                                                              
    {                                                                                                        
        inZoo = (Zoo)inObject;                                                                               
        if(count == inZoo.getCount())                                                                        
        {                                                                                                    
            if(sameAs(animals,inZoo.getAnimals()))                                                           
            {                                                                                                
                same = true;                                                                                 
            }                                                                                                
        }                                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                        
    return same;                                                                                             
}                                                                                                            

public String toString()                                                                                     
{                                                                                                            
    String outString = "Count: " + count;                                                                    
    for(int ii = 0; ii < animals.length; ii++)                                                               
    {                                                                                                        
         outString = outString + ("Animals" + ii + ": " + animals[ii].toString());                           
    }                                                                                                        
    return outString;                                                                                        
}                                                                                                            

public void addFlying()                                                                                      
{                                                                                                            
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);                                                                     
    String species;                                                                                          
    int numWings;                                                                                            
    double mass;                                                                                             
    System.out.println("Please enter the Species of the Flying Animal.");                                    
    species = sc.nextLine();                                                                                 
    System.out.println("Please enter the Mass of the Flying Animal.");                                       
    mass = sc.nextDouble();                                                                                  
    System.out.println("Please enter the Number of Wings the Flying Animal has.");                           
    numWings = sc.nextInt();                                                                                 
    Flying temp = new Flying(species,mass,numWings);                                                         
    animals[count] = temp;                                                                                   
    System.out.println("Animal has been added to the Zoo.");                                                 
    count++;                                                                                                 
}                                                                                                      
public void addTerrestrial()                                                                                 
{                                                                                                            
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);                                                                     
    String species;                                                                                          
    int numLegs;                                                                                             
    double mass;                                                                                             
    System.out.println("Please enter the Species of the Terrestrial Animal.");                               
    species = sc.nextLine();                                                                                 
    System.out.println("Please enter the Mass of the Terrestrial Animal.");                                  
    mass = sc.nextDouble();                                                                                  
    System.out.println("Please enter the Number of Legs that the Terrestrial Animal has.");                  
    numLegs = sc.nextInt();                                                                                  
    Terrestrial temp = new Terrestrial(numLegs,mass,species);                                                
    animals[count] = temp;                                                                                   
    System.out.println("Animal has been added to the Zoo.");                                                 
    count++;                                                                                                 
}                                                                                 
public void addAquatic()                                                                                     
{                                                                                                            
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);                                                                     
    String species;                                                                                          
    int numFins;                                                                                             
    double mass;                                                                                             
    System.out.println("Please enter the Species of the Aquatic Animal.");                                   
    species = sc.nextLine();                                                                                 
    System.out.println("Please enter the Mass of the Aquatic Animal.");                                      
    mass = sc.nextDouble();                                                                                  
    System.out.println("Please enter the Number of Fins that the Aquatic Animal has.");                      
    numFins = sc.nextInt();                                                                                  
    Aquatic temp = new Aquatic(mass,species,numFins);                                                        
    animals[count] = temp;                                                                                   
    System.out.println("Animal has been added to the Zoo.");                                                 
    count++;                                                                                                 
}                                                                           
public void displayAnimals()                                                                                 
{                                                                                                            
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)                                                                               
    {                                                                                                        
        if(animals[i] instanceof Flying)                                                                     
        {                                                                                                    
            Flying test1 = new Flying((Flying)animals[i]);                                                   
            System.out.println(test1.toString());                                                            
        }                                                                                                    
        if(animals[i] instanceof Terrestrial)                                                                
        {                                                                                                    
            Terrestrial test2 = new Terrestrial((Terrestrial)animals[i]);                                    
            System.out.println(test2.toString());                                                            
        }                                                                                                    
        if(animals[i] instanceof Aquatic)                                                                    
        {                                                                                                    
            Aquatic test3 = new Aquatic((Aquatic)animals[i]);                                                
            System.out.println(test3.toString());                                                            
        }                                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                        
}                                                                                                                           
public Animals[] readFile()                                                                                  
{                                                                                                            
    try                                                                                                      
    {                                                                                                        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);                                                                 
        System.out.println("Enter the file name.");                                                          
        String fileName = sc.nextLine();                                                                     
        String string;                                                                                       
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));                        
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();                                                         
        for(int a = 0; a<animals.length; a++)                                                                
        {                                                                                                    
            while((string = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)                                              
            {                                                                                                
                list.add(string);                                                                            
            }                                                                                                
            animals = list.toArray(new Animals[a]);                                                          
        }                                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                        

    catch(IOException e)                                                                                     
    {                                                                                                        
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());                                                                  
    }                                                                                                        
    catch(ArrayStoreException e2)                                                                            
    {                                                                                                        
        System.out.println("Attempt to Store wrong type of object into an array of objects.");               
    }                                                                                                        
    return animals;                                                                                          
}                                                                                                                                                  
//Private Submodules                                                                      
private boolean sameAs(Object[] array1, Object[] array2)                                                     
{                                                                                                            
    boolean sameAs = true;                                                                                   
    if(array1.length != array2.length)                                                                       
    {                                                                                                        
        sameAs = false;                                                                                      
    }                                                                                                        
    else                                                                                                     
    {                                                                                                        
        int count = 0;                                                                                       
        do                                                                                                   
        {                                                                                                    
            sameAs = array1[count].equals(array2[count]);                                                    
            count++;                                                                                         
        }                                                                                                    
        while(sameAs && (count < array1.length));                                                            
    }                                                                                                        
    return sameAs;                                                                                           
}                                                                                                            


private boolean validateCount(int inCount)                                                                   
{                                                                                                            
    return((inCount > 0) && (inCount <= 20));                                                                
}                                                                                                            
}
```

And it is the readFile submodule which I'm experiencing problems with. Everything else works fine and the files compile. 
Any solutions are welcome, I've been racking my brain for hours.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to convert a `List<String>` into an array of `Animals`.  A `String` is not an `Animals`, so this is never going to work.  That's what your error is telling you.

To be able to give you more guidance on how to fix this, I'd need to see your `Animals` class, and the structure of your input file.  You haven't shown either of these here.

Comment: F,Condor,15.95,4                                                                                                 


F,Crested Pidgeon,0.49,2                                                                                         


T,Rhinoceros,1550,4                                                                                              
Here is the input file.

A,Great White Shark,1800,31,3                                                                                    


T,Shrew,0.28,2 - Format is hard to do on stack.

Comment: I cant post animals class because Stack limits me with characters. Basically the animal array has 3 types of animals, Terrestrial,Flying and Aquatic. Each Animal type has a species, mass and number of wings/legs/fins.

Comment: Well, the bottom line is that you'll need to  write some code that converts a line of that file into an `Animals` object.  Java won't magically convert a `String` to an `Animals` for  you.